# How to convert JS Object to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

I need to convert a hash map

```
{ 
    "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],
    "veg"   : ["carrot"]
}
```

to

```
[ 
  { "type" : "fruit" , "name" : ["mango","orange"] } ,
  { "type" : "veg" ,   "name" : ["carrot"] } 
]
```

how do I do that??

Comment: I would like to know how to do it both ways..

Comment: please, remember to always provide some code identation, it makes the question easier to read

Comment: thanks for the edit...will remember it nxt time..

Comment: Note that JavaScript has no "hash map", just "objects".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do it like this (in a working snippet):

```js
var input = { 
    "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],
    "veg"   : ["carrot"]
} 

var output = [], item;

for (var type in input) {
    item = {};
    item.type = type;
    item.name = input[type];
    output.push(item);
}

// display result
document.write(JSON.stringify(output));
```

---

Or, if you or someone else has been extending the `Object` prototype with enumerable properties (which I think is a bad practice personally), then you could use this to protect from that:

```js
var input = { 
    "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],
    "veg"   : ["carrot"]
} 

var output = [], item;

for (var type in input) {
    if (input.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
        item = {};
        item.type = type;
        item.name = input[type];
        output.push(item);
    }
}

// display result
document.write(JSON.stringify(output));
```

---

And, using some more modern functionality:

```js
var input = { 
    "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],
    "veg"   : ["carrot"]
};

var output = Object.keys(input).map(function(key) {
   return {type: key, name: input[key]};
});

// display the result
document.write(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: I suggest checking `hasOwnProperty` inside the `for...in` loop.

Comment: @Rocket I do NOT suggest checking hasOwnProperty inside the for...in loop.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: Please explain why.

Comment: @Rocket: Why would someone do that if they haven't extended `Object.prototype`?

Comment: @amnotiam: What if I decide to run `Object.prototype.test = 'test'` on your page, just for the hell of it.  BAM!  Broke your script :-P

Comment: @amnotiam: JavaScipt console.  `javascript:Object.prototype.test = 'test'` in the address bar.  Greasemonkey script/browser plugin.  Plenty of ways.

Comment: @Rocket see my question for discussion, it is anyway not place for such extended dicussions

Comment: I gave the OP either option in my answer (with or without `hasOwnProperty()`).  I don't personally allow extension of `Object` in my pages so I don't have to add extra code to protect from it.  If I was in an environment where that was a possibility, I would code to protect from it.

Comment: Added a more modern version using `Object.keys()` and `.map()` and made all the examples into working snippets.

Answer (score 28):

In a browser that supports ES5 – or where you added a [shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for it:

```
var stuff = { 
    "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],
    "veg"   : ["carrot"]
}

var array = Object.keys(stuff).map(function(key) {
    return {"type" : key, "name" : stuff[key] }
})
```

See: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array's map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Or, in the old fashion way:

```
var stuff = { 
    "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],
    "veg"   : ["carrot"]
}

var array = []

for (var key in stuff) {
    if (stuff.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        array.push({"type" : key, "name" : stuff[key] })
    }
}
```

Please notice that in both cases the array's value are shared because in JS the objects are passed by reference. So, for instance, `stuff["fruit"]` and `array[0].name` points to the same reference of the array `["mango", "orange"]`. It means, if you change one of them, the other will be changed as well:

```
stuff["fruit"].push("apple");
alert(array[0].name); // "mango", "orange", "apple"
```

To avoid that, you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to have a one-level deep copy of your array. So in the code above, instead of:

```
"name" : stuff[key]
```

you will have:

```
"name" : stuff[key].slice(0)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

For those using ES6 maps...

Assuming you have...

```
const m = new Map()
m.set("fruit",["mango","orange"]);
m.set("veg",["carrot"]);
```

You can use...

```
const arr = Array.from(map, ([key, val]) => {
  return {type: key, name: val};
});
```

Note that [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) takes iterables as well as array-like objects.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to give an "oneline" solution:

```
var b = Object.keys(a).map(e => { return { type:e, name:a[e] } });
```

Economy of words at your service. Question asked for translating an object to an array, so I'm not duplicating above answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks simple, key of your map is type and values are name, so just loop thru map and insert object in a list e.g.

```
var d = { "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],"veg" :["carrot"]} 
var l = []
for(var type in d){
    l.push({'type':type, 'name': d[type]})
}
console.log(l)
```

output:

```
[{"type":"fruit","name":["mango","orange"]},{"type":"veg","name":["carrot"]}]
```

Comment: as a good practice it's better to also use `.hasOwnProperty()` method

Comment: @F.Calderan why that is necessary in this case, when format is fixed map?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: Because without `hasOwnProperty`, your `for... in` loop will read values from up the prototype chain.  For example `Object.prototype.test = 'test'`.  Your loop will read this value, `hasOwnProperty` checks to see if the value is from the object itself, and not its prototype chain.

Comment: I didn't say it's necessary but we can't say if that object has some other properties added via `Object.prototype`

Comment: so, what if it is not a fixed map??

Comment: @F.Calderan: Unless you have code that adds enumerable properties to `Object.prototype`, it isn't necessary. It does not make any sense to use `hasOwnProperty` if you haven't done that.

Comment: @F.Calderan in will depend on the problem and how dict was constructed but in this scenario I will discourage such usage when I know I have a plain JavaScript object, it is like premature optimization and decreases readablity

Comment: @Sam by fixed map I know it has required properties and you have created it thru normal object creation or from json, it will work for all such maps.

Comment: @amnotiam: I think it's good to use `hasOwnProperty` anyway, so if there's ever a case where's it's needed, you won't forget. :-P

Comment: it is not about _premature optimization_: it's only just good practice and headaches prevention

Comment: @amnotiam: What I run `Object.prototype.test = 'test'` on your page?  `hasOwnProperty` will prevent me from breaking your page :-)

Comment: @Rocket in that case why not check that if key is not a function, or many such checks or may in some case we do want parent properties so add an option for that too

Comment: @Rocket: I don't understand. How is your code getting on my page? :)

Comment: @amnotiam: JavaScipt console.  `javascript:Object.prototype.test = 'test'` in the address bar.  Greasemonkey script/browser plugin.  Plenty of ways.

Comment: @Rocket: That doesn't make much sense. Why would a person sabotage the page they're visiting? If they want to do that, it's fine, but it's an academic point at best.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: `Object.prototype.myArray = [1,2,3]`.  This isn't a function.  Why check for every scenario when `hasOwnProperty` is easy? :-P

Comment: @Rocket what about some one inserting wrong fruits e.g mymapp['fruits'] = 'bacon', or adding a function directly to my object so I filter them out too

Comment: @amnotiamIt's not a matter of sabotage: what if another js library makes addition to Object.prototype. How can you be sure that this won't never happen?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: What are you talking about?  That's why you *never* use global variables :-P

Comment: @F.Calderan: Ignorance of the code you're using isn't a very good argument. A programmer should know what a library does before using it. If it extends `Object.prototype`, you should stop using it. And Rocket's example was one of sabotage.

Comment: @Rocket that is why libraries should not modify object prototype and if lib do that don't use it, I am full control on my pages

Comment: @F.Calderan: And to your question *"How can you be sure that this won't never happen?"*, it's trivial to test for `Object.prototype` extensions if you're really that worried about it.

Comment: @amnotiam: What if this array was then sent to a server via AJAX.  What if I'm an evil hacker?  Enough of the "what if"s.  `hasOwnProperty` will make sure your array is what you want.  `Object.prototype` can be extended legitimately.  I think it's a good habit to use `hasOwnProperty`, so you don't forget when it's really needed.  It'll save headaches.

Comment: @amnotiam: `hasOwnProperty` is even more trivial, and less code :-P

Comment: @Rocket: If you've been hacked, `Object.prototype` is the least of your concerns. An AJAX request makes no difference. You should know the code you're using.

Comment: @Rocket: `hasOwnProperty` for every property in every enumeration you do is more code, and more overhead. Why check every property in ever enumeration, when you could check once in the beginning?

Comment: @amnotiam: Sometimes it's the simple things that get hacked.  The spot where you'd never look.  Your weak spot.

Comment: @Rocket: Then you must guard against every built in object and property that could possibly be modified. Right?

Comment: @amnotiam: Why the heck would you do `for(var i in 12)` or `for(var i in "dog")`?

Comment: @Rocket: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @amnotiam: Why does it matter if other prototypes are extended?  You're never gonna be looping over 'em?  Anyway, I don't want to argue too much.  I've just always been taught to use `hasOwnProperty`, and I haven't heard many good arguments why I shouldn't.

Comment: @Rocket if somebody can modify object without me knowing then he can change e.g. `Array.prototype.join = function(){alert("hacked!")}` now will you say I should be using any array methods at all

Comment: @Rocket: I wasn't talking about other prototypes being extended. I meant that if hackers go for the small stuff, you'd need to guard against any and all possible modifications to the environment. For example, what if someone does `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function() { alert('foo'); }`?

Comment: @amnotiam: Yeah, I guess you're right.  I didn't think of that. X_X  You win :-P  Thanks for a fun argument, I learned something new :-D

Comment: If you want to continue this discussion, please use [chat].

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you are looking for, but it could be useful for general purpose.

```
var hash2Array = function(hash, valueOnly) {
  return Object.keys(hash).map(function(k) {
    if (valueOnly) {
      return hash[k];
    } else {
      var obj={};
      obj[k] = hash[k];
      return obj;
    }
  });
};

//output
hash2Array({a:1, b:2});     // [{a:1}, {b:2}]
hash2Array({a:1, b:2},true) // [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of using underscore.js:

```
var original = { 
   "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],
   "veg"   : ["carrot"]
}
var converted = _.map(original, function(name, type){
   return {
      type: type, 
      name: name
   };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

No Need of loop

```
var a = { 
   "fruit" : ["mango","orange"],    
   "veg"   : ["carrot"]


};  

var b = [  
    { "type" : "fruit" , "pop" : function(){this.name = a[this.type]; delete this.pop; return this} }.pop() ,          
    { "type" : "veg" ,   "pop" : function(){this.name = a[this.type]; delete this.pop; return this} }.pop()   
]
```

Comment: that's...bizarre.  at least reuse the function ;)