# Sorting a JSON OBJECT (different order in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

i want to sort a json Object by the key, Chrome keep the order i need, but firefox dont.

Here's an example of my json object :

```
{
  "media": {
    "1387185503": {
      "id_profil": "7256",
      "photo_profil": "http://www.mupiz.com/7256/picture",
      "phrase_feed": "a ajouté une nouvelle vidéo",
      "nom_media": "Jam a la casserole",
      "nom_profil": "Camille Boullier de Branche",
      "url_profil": "camille-boullier-de-branche",
      "streaming": "<iframe width=\"270\" height=\"200\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/K6i_avCwsvQ?html5=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
      "url_media": "http://www.mupiz.com/camille-boullier-de-branche/video/jam-a-la-casserole"
    },
    "1387185460": {
      "id_profil": "7256",
      "photo_profil": "http://www.mupiz.com/7256/picture",
      "phrase_feed": "a ajouté une nouvelle vidéo",
      "nom_media": "festival silhouette 2010 avec IGIT",
      "nom_profil": "Camille Boullier de Branche",
      "url_profil": "camille-boullier-de-branche",
      "streaming": "<object width=\"270px\" height=\"200px\" ><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/xet02y&related=0&colors=background:000000;foreground:FFFFFF;special:88868A;\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/xet02y&related=0&colors=background:000000;foreground:FFFFFF;special:88868A;\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"270\" wmode=\"transparent\"  height=\"200\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\"></embed></object>",
      "url_media": "http://www.mupiz.com/camille-boullier-de-branche/video/festival-silhouette-2010-avec-igit"
    },
    "1385912810": {
      "id_profil": "36541",
      "photo_profil": "http://www.mupiz.com/36541/picture",
      "phrase_feed": "a ajouté une nouvelle chanson",
      "nom_media": "Sans titre",
      "nom_profil": "Eve IBK",
      "url_profil": "evelyne-zyss",
      "streaming": "\r\n  <div class=\"playerMedia\" onclick=\"InlinePlayer(this)\" data-url=\"http://www.mupiz.com/mp3/36541/mp3_85725.mp3\" data-id=\"mp3_85725.mp3\">Sans titre</div>\r\n",
      "url_media": "http://www.mupiz.com/evelyne-zyss/"
    }, .....
```

I want to sort this part of my json object with the timestamp asc not desc like this.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Hash has NO order, so if you are trying to expect it to look ordered, its a fluke (it is a random event)

Comment: BTW: Just because Chrome does it, it doesn't mean it makes sense :)

Comment: BTW: It could be that FF is showing it as it was received, while Chrome is showing it rendered (i.e. stored), so both are "right" just the display is "different"

Comment: Ok, what can i do ? Changing the object into an array and order it ?

Comment: Why do you need it sorted?, is it for debugging? or actual use? if it is actual use, best would be to put it into an array, then sort by the timestamp value, i.e. put the timestamp a value of each of the items in the array, the use that value as the sorting agent

Comment: Any ideas to transform efficiently my object into an array with KEY = My timestamp and VALUE = the datas?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336794/converting-hash-map-to-array

Answer (score 2):

Browsers auto-sort" JSON properties when they are 'strigify' numbers:

For example this will have the same behavior in **Chrome** and **Firexfox**:

```
 var an_obj = { "4": "d", "1": "a", "2": "c"};
 alert(Object.keys(an_obj)); //will alert 1, 2, 4
```

In case of your Sample JSON

**Chrome:**

```
var an_obj = { "1387185460": "a", "1387185503": "b", "1385912810": "c"};
alert(Object.keys(an_obj)); // will alert "1385912810, 1387185460, 1387185503"
```

While **Firefox** it is actually retaining the original state:

```
var an_obj = { "1387185460": "a", "1387185503": "b", "1385912810": "c"};
 alert(Object.keys(an_obj)); // will alert "1387185460, 1387185503, 1385912810"
```

This occurs because the Firefox sorting algorithm will work only when the first 3 characters are not exactly the same. For instance:

**Chrome**

```
  var value2 = {"1003":1, "1001":2, "1000":3};
  alert(Object.keys(value2)); // will alert 1000, 1001, 1003
```

**Firefox** will retain the original order:

```
 var value2 = {"1003":1, "1001":2, "1000":3};
 alert(Object.keys(value2)); // will alert 1003, 1001, 1000
```

This is actually a [known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865760) by Firefox Team. Enumeration ordering is unspecified as part of [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) and therefore you should not rely on it. This is expected to be resolved in ES7 implementation.

Regarding your problem at hand, this what I would do:

```
var arr = {
        "media": {
            "1387185503": {
                "id_profil": "7256",
                "photo_profil": "http://www.mupiz.com/7256/picture",
                "phrase_feed": "a ajouté une nouvelle vidéo",
                "nom_media": "Jam a la casserole",
                "nom_profil": "Camille Boullier de Branche",
                "url_profil": "camille-boullier-de-branche",
                "streaming": "<iframe width=\"270\" height=\"200\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/K6i_avCwsvQ?html5=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                "url_media": "http://www.mupiz.com/camille-boullier-de-branche/video/jam-a-la-casserole"
            },
            "1387185460": {
                "id_profil": "7256",
                "photo_profil": "http://www.mupiz.com/7256/picture",
                "phrase_feed": "a ajouté une nouvelle vidéo",
                "nom_media": "festival silhouette 2010 avec IGIT",
                "nom_profil": "Camille Boullier de Branche",
                "url_profil": "camille-boullier-de-branche",
                "streaming": "<object width=\"270px\" height=\"200px\" ><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/xet02y&related=0&colors=background:000000;foreground:FFFFFF;special:88868A;\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/xet02y&related=0&colors=background:000000;foreground:FFFFFF;special:88868A;\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"270\" wmode=\"transparent\"  height=\"200\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\"></embed></object>",
                "url_media": "http://www.mupiz.com/camille-boullier-de-branche/video/festival-silhouette-2010-avec-igit"
            },
            "1385912810": {
                "id_profil": "36541",
                "photo_profil": "http://www.mupiz.com/36541/picture",
                "phrase_feed": "a ajouté une nouvelle chanson",
                "nom_media": "Sans titre",
                "nom_profil": "Eve IBK",
                "url_profil": "evelyne-zyss",
                "streaming": "\r\n  <div class=\"playerMedia\" onclick=\"InlinePlayer(this)\" data-url=\"http://www.mupiz.com/mp3/36541/mp3_85725.mp3\" data-id=\"mp3_85725.mp3\">Sans titre</div>\r\n",
                "url_media": "http://www.mupiz.com/evelyne-zyss/"
            }
        }
    };
 var properties=Object.keys( arr.media).sort();
 arr.media = properties.reduce(function(res, prop){
           res[prop] = arr.media[prop];
           return res;
       },{});
```

and Alternate solution is to implement toJSON:

```
arr.media.toJSON = function(){
            var newMedia = properties.reverse().reduce(function(res, prop){
                res[prop] = arr.media[prop];
                return res;
            },{});
           return newMedia;
       };
 var newSortedObject =(JSON.stringify(arr.media));
```

Hope this helps