# Python json dumps always sorts dictionary, how to prevent it from sorting it

Tags: python, json

I am using python 3 and have a flask app.

At one point I have this dictionary right before i return the json object with `json.dumps`. The order is always random:

```
{2352: '3', 2353: '4', 2351: '2', 2350: '1'}
```

The problem is that in the console (browser dev tools) the dictionary is always sorted:

```
answers: {…}
​​
2350: "1"
​​
2351: "2"
​​
2352: "3"
​​
2353: "4"
```

So I assume the sorting happens here:

```
return json.dumps({'answers' : answers}, sort_keys=False)
```

Question:

**Why does `json.dumps` sort the dictionary, I thought python dictionaries have no order.**

Side note:

I use this function to either create a random order or a sorted order:

```
if question.random_answer_positions is False:
    print ('does not randomize answers in ajax')
    for answer in question.belongs_to_question_id_addresses:
        answers[answer.id] = answer.answer
else:
    print ('randomize answers in ajax')
    for answer in random.shuffle(list(question.belongs_to_question_id_addresses)):
        answers[answer.id] = answer.answer
```

Comment: It's likely that the browser dev tools are the ones doing the sorting.  Try doing an HTTP request directly with curl or `requests` or the like and see what you get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just see the output in the interpreter:

```
>>> json.dumps({2352: '3', 2353: '4', 2351: '2', 2350: '1'})
'{"2352": "3", "2353": "4", "2351": "2", "2350": "1"}'
```

So there is *no* sorting.

Therefore your assumption that `json.dumps` is sorting the dictionary is false. It must be your browser's dev tools...

Comment: But than my returns are not reliable, how would I fix such a thing if the browser decides to sort my dict. Is there a documentation on this?

Comment: @Roman It may be documented for your browser, but I would suggest you use an array instead. For any situation where order is important (even if it is important that it is *not* sorted), use an array. Only use a dictionary when you *don't* care about the order.

Comment: It seems its a reported [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840914/sorting-a-json-object-different-order-in-firefox), thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: "Browsers auto-sort" JSON properties when they are 'strigify' numbers"