# Converting Map<String,String> into array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dictionary

I have Map in java like this :

```
"{one=Print, two=Email, three=Download, four=Send to Cloud}";
```

I need to convert above string to array in jquery and loop the array and fetch respective key and value

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting hash map to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336794/converting-hash-map-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) , [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) methods.

```js
var str = "{one=Print, two=Email, three=Download, four=Send to Cloud}";

str
// remove the space at start and end
  .trim()
  // get string without `{` and `}`
  .slice(1, -1)
  // split by `,`
  .split(',')
  // iterate over the array
  .forEach(function(v) {
    // split by `=`
    var val = v.trim().split('=');
    console.log('key : ' + val[0] + ", value : " + val[1])
  })
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to generate an object then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var str = "{one=Print, two=Email, three=Download, four=Send to Cloud}";

var res = str
  .trim()
  .slice(1, -1)
  .split(',')
  .reduce(function(obj, v) {
    var val = v.trim().split('=');
    // define object property
    obj[val[0]] = val[1];
    // return object reference
    return obj;
    // set initial parameter as empty object
  }, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: .reduce() is not supported in ie8 is there any alternative for this

Comment: @user3044552 :  check polyfill : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple hack:

```
let arr = jsons.replace('{','').replace('}','').split(',')
arr.map((each)=>{let newVal = each.split('='); return {key: newVal[0], value: newVal[1]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function convertString(string) {
  return string.split(', ').map(function(a) {
    var kvArr = a.split('=');
    return {key: kvArr[0], value: kvArr[1]};
  };
}
```

```js
function convertString(string) {
      string = string.slice(1, string.length - 1);
      return string.split(', ').map(function(a) {
        var kvArr = a.split('=');
        return {key: kvArr[0], value: kvArr[1]};
      });
}

alert(JSON.stringify(convertString("{one=Print, two=Email, three=Download, four=Send to Cloud}")));
```