# Jquery: Convert string dictionary array into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, dictionary

My data is coming in this way:

```
time_slot = "[{\"id\": \"3\",\"table\": \"Table 1\",\"time\": \"10:00-11:00},
{\"id\": \"4\",\"table\": \"Table 1\",\"time\": \"02:00-03:00\"},
{\"id\": \"8\",\"table\": \"Table 2\",\"time\": \"10:00-11:00\"},
{\"id\": \"10\",\"table\": \"Table 2\",\"time\": \"02:00-03:00\"}]"
```

I want to have result like that:

```
[{id:3,table:"Table 1",time:"10:00-11:00"},
{id:4,table:"Table 2",time:"02:00-03:00},
.....
]
```

and i am trying to convert them by using this.

i tried this from here [Converting Map<String,String> into array in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882019/converting-mapstring-string-into-array-in-jquery):

```
let arr = time_slot.replace('{','').replace('}','').replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')
arr.map((each)=>{let newVal = each.split('='); return {key: newVal[0], value: newVal[1]}})
```

but not getting desire results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fix your json and convert string Id to number

```
time_slot=time_slot.replaceAll("},{","\"},{").replace("}]","\"}]");
var times=JSON.parse(time_slot);
times.forEach(item => {
    item.id=parseInt(item.id);
});

console.log(times);
```

result

```
[{"id":3,"table":"Table 1","time":"10:00-11:00"},
{"id":4,"table":"Table 1","time":"02:00-03:00"},
{"id":8,"table":"Table 2","time":"10:00-11:00"},
{"id":10,"table":"Table 2","time":"02:00-03:00"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a missing closing quote `"` for the `time` value. If that is just a typo you can simply convert

```
JSON.parse(time_slot).map(r => ({...r, id: +r.id}))
```