# Convert a map to an array - Angular 6 and JHipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

**Goal:** To convert a map that I retrieved from a server to a array in order to make it appear in the HTML. Indeed, I could see in the forums that a map is not suitable for an *ngFor structural directive.

**Try:**

The map looks like this (in reality there are also objects inside the objects but I don't think it changes a lot the result):

{

"Mission 1":[
{
"id": 1
"quantite":0
"date" : 2018-04-01
},
{
"id": 2
"quantite":0
"date" : 2018-04-02
}
],

"Mission 2":[
{
"id": 3
"quantite":0
"date" : 2018-04-01
},
{
"id": 4
"quantite":0
"date" : 2018-04-02
}
]

}

I tried to use this code:

```
     this.mapToArray = Array.from(this.map);
```

**Issue:** Well the map is found. But then, for mapToArray, it is set to undefined like nothing happened with the Array.from(map).

Could you help me please?

Thanks!

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

Hey,

Thanks for your answers.

First, the methods related to a map like forEach() and others do not work. I might be wrong but from what I saw during my researches, the Map interface is not available in TypeScript (which is the language used in Angular 5-6). I tried the solutions you suggested but I couldn't make it work.

Second, I made little advances but I lack something. If you have any idea:

**TypeScript Side**

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {



map: { [index:string], ArrayList:Details } = {};

valueMission: ArrayList<Details>;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ details }) => {
        this.map = details;
        this.valueMission = this.map["Mission 1"];
    });

    }
```

**HTML Side**

```
<p> {{valueMission[0].dayOfMonth}}</p>
```

**Comment**

So this works. In my HTML table, the dayOfMonth is shown. Now, what I need to do is to create an array for the keys, to be able to create a corresponding array like valueMission for each key and then be able to show them in the HTML. Any clue?

Thanks,

Manu

Comment: `Array.from({ foo: "bar" })` is an empty array. What output are you *expecting* here?

Comment: In the front, I would like to create a new line for each Mission. In each line, I would like to add a new field for each date. So I would like an array of keys. And then for each key an array of value.

Comment: I am not sure of the structure of the map you have provided is in proper format.

      {

"Mission 1":[ { "id": 1, "quantite":0, "date" : 2018-04-01 }, { "id": 2, "quantite":0, "date" : 2018-04-02 } ],

"Mission 2":[ { "id": 3 ,"quantite":0 ,"date" : 2018-04-01 }, { "id": 4, "quantite":0, "date" : 2018-04-02 } ]

}
 formatted the above map.

Comment: This isn't really specific to either [tag:angular] or [tag:jhipster]. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336794/how-to-convert-js-object-to-array.

Comment: Yes Prabhat Gundepalli. There are comma in my file. I just didn't copy it well. Thanks for the link jonrsharpe. I will try this.

Comment: @ManuelaCodingPadawan Could you please try the answer I have posted??

Comment: @JEMI Yes, I'll try this morning Thanks.

Comment: looking at your updated answer, are you positive that `details` in your `subscribe` callback looks exactly like what you posted?  Can you confirm that by outputting the results of `details` to confirm that it looks the way you think it looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data {} is an object , first of all I would suggest you to convert the same in to an array and apply a map function. Inside map function you have to do a filter function , because again you have an inner objects of **missions**

```
 var data = {

            "Mission 1": [{
                "id": 1,
                "quantite": 0,
                "date": 2018 - 04 - 01
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "quantite": 0,
                "date": 2018 - 04 - 02
            }],

            "Mission 2": [{
                "id": 3,
                "quantite": 0,
                "date": 2018 - 04 - 01
            }, {
                "id": 4,
                "quantite": 0,
                "date": 2018 - 04 - 02
            }]

        };



    var anArray = [];
//push to an empty array if the data is an object to apply map function
            anArray.push(data)
            var data1 = anArray.map(function (item) {
                var items = [];
                Object.keys(item).forEach(function (key, index) {                        
                    item[key].forEach(function (inneritem, index) {
                        items.push(inneritem);
                    });
                });
                return items;
            });

            var allDatas = data1[0];
```

Comment: Hey JEMI, I need to enter the name of the key and of the index each time? Because I can't do it in a lot of data...

Comment: @ManuelaCodingPadawan No..that i just commented what’s index and key..you don’t need to specify anything..you just apply the map func on the top of your array.just try the code, you will get it what I wrote

Comment: @ManuelaCodingPadawan I removed the comment to avoid confusion , when iterate the object keys , the key and index will automatically pass to the callback function

Answer (score 0):

you can do that :

```js
var obj = {
      "Mission 1": [{
          "id": 1,
          "quantite": 0,
          "date": 2018 - 04 - 01
      }, {
          "id": 2,
          "quantite": 0,
          "date": 2018 - 04 - 02
      }],

      "Mission 2": [{
          "id": 3,
          "quantite": 0,
          "date": 2018 - 04 - 01
      }, {
          "id": 4,
          "quantite": 0,
          "date": 2018 - 04 - 02
      }]

     };
     
     var array = [];
     var i = 0;
     for (var mission in obj) {
       array[i] = array.concat(obj[mission]);
       i++;
     }
     
     console.log(array);
```

Comment: what if the collection have 50 mission??

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but I don't succeed to make your code work..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data looks like this:

```
data = {

    "Mission 1":[ { "id": 1 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-01 }, { "id": 2 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-02 } ],

    "Mission 2":[ { "id": 3 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-01 }, { "id": 4 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-02 } ]

}
```

then, you can get an array of all the items in data by mapping over the keys, i.e.

```
let result = Object.keys(dataKey => {
   // here, dataKey will be -> "Mission 1", then "Mission 2" etc...
   // the value you return here will be used to form the elements of your array
   // so do whatever transformation you want to do here
   return data[dataKey];
});
```

`result` will end up being an array looking like:

```
[
   [ { "id": 1 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-01 }, { "id": 2 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-02 } ],
   [ { "id": 3 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-01 }, { "id": 4 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-02 } ]

]
```

Of course, it's unlikely that you'd want an array of arrays, so within the callback, you can transform each element of your result into whatever makes sense.
So, for eg, if instead of an array of arrays, I could flatten it to a single result by doing:

```
let result = Object.keys(dataKey => {
   // here, dataKey will be -> "Mission 1", then "Mission 2" etc...
   // in this case, i want the first data item of each 'mission'
   return data[dataKey][0];
});
```

and `result` will be:

```
 [
   { "id": 1 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-01 },
   { "id": 3 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-01 },
]
```

or another example,

```
 let result2 = Object.keys(missionName => {
   // here, dataKey will be -> "Mission 1", then "Mission 2" etc...
   return {
       missionName: missionName,
       firstMission: data[missionName][0],
       missions: data[missionName],
   };
});
```

and `result2` will look like:

```
[
 {
   missionName: "Mission 1",
   firstMission: { "id": 1 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-01 },
   missions: [
    { "id": 1 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-01 }, 
    { "id": 2 "quantite":0 "date" : 2018-04-02 }
   ],
 }, 
 {
   missionName: "Mission 2", 
   ....
 }
]
```

and so forth. Really, what happens within that callback all depends on what you want your final result to look like.

Comment: I would like to have access both to the key and to the array. Indeed, in the HTML part, I would like a row with first the name of the mission (so the key) and following I would like to show each day in line corresponding  to each mission... I don't succeed to do it with the code you provide me. How do you reach the key also?

Comment: As i mentioned, in the example I gave, dataKey is the mission name in your `data` object. So, you can use that to construct whatever data structure you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments. Each of them helped me. I resolved my issue.

**One solution:**

```
 this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ details }) => {
        this.map = details;

        const keysOfMap = Object.keys(details);

        const arrayOfArrays: ArrayList = [];

        for (let keyOfMap in keysOfMap){

            const valueMission = this.map[keysOfMap[keyOfMap]];

            arrayOfArrays.push(valueMission);
        }

        this.arrayOfArrays = arrayOfArrays;
        this.keysOfMap = keysOfMap;
    });
```

Then those two arrays can be treated like any array in HTML view.

Thanks again for your time!